# import package in jupyter notebook installed with pip development mode

Tags: python, import, package, jupyter, conda

I'm using anaconda to manage a virtual environment. I'm developing some Jupyter Notebooks and I'm using some functions in multiple Notebooks. So I want to extract these functions in a package, lets call it `mytools` and `import mytools` in my Notebooks. I installed the tools package from the parent dir with:

```
source activate myenv
pip install -e ./mytools/
```

And run the jupyter notebook server

```
source activate myenv
jupyter notebook
```

When I execute `import mytools` I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-cbc927808b4d> in <module>()
----> 1 import mytools

ImportError: No module named 'mytools'
```

Why can't I import it in the juypter notebook?

When I run `pip list` in the conda environment I can see the installed package.

When I run:

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

it points to the myenv environment `/Users/me/anaconda/envs/myenv/bin/python`

My Folder structure:

```
├── Notebook Project1
│    └── Notebook1.ipynb
├── Notebook Project2
│    └── Notebook2.ipynb
└── mytools
     ├── __init__.py
     ├── module1
     │    ├── modulecode.py
     │    └── __init__.py
     ├── module2
     │    ├── modulecode.py
     │    └── __init__.py
     └── setup.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an error in the setup.py file.

This helped me to solve the errors: https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html